# Gödel numbers of proofs

Tags: logic

On page 233 of Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic", item 21. Enderton defines a function g(s):

g(s) = the least d such that s is not the Gödel number of a sentence, or d is in the set of item 18 and the last component of d is either s or is ¬s

What is the point of the first disjunct of this definition? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: I suggest that you would write the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

If $s$ is the Gödel number of a sentence $\sigma$, you then have that $g(\sharp\sigma)$ is $\mathcal{G}$ of the least deduction of $\sigma$ or $\neg\sigma$ from $A$ (see item $18$ page $232$).

Otherwise, if $s$ not the Gödel number of a sentence, you get $g(s)=0$.

Comment: Ah, yes, to account for the cases in which g(s) = 0. Thanks!

Comment: @user65526 Well, technically, to account for the cases where $s$ is not the GN of a sentence.